# Inverse function of integral $f(x)=\int_{0}^x \frac{dt}{\sqrt{1+t^3}}$

Tags: calculus, integration, definite-integrals

I have the next problem:

> Be
>   $$f(x)=\int_{0}^x \frac{dt}{\sqrt{1+t^3}}$$
>   and $g$ is the inverse function of $f$. Find the value of *k* such that
>   $$g''(y)=kg^2(y)$$

I do not how to solve this, I've tried *the fundamental theorem of calculus* and the application of inverse and composition $g(f(x))=x$ But it seems pretty confusing. Any help will be appreciated

Comment: Please check my edit!

Comment: Take the derivative of $f(g(x))=x$ to get$$f'(g(x))g'(x)=1$$Or, rearranging,$$g'(x)=\frac1{f'(g(x))}$$Can you differentiate once more, using the fundamental theorem of calculus to evaluate $f'$ and $f''$?

Comment: $f$ is an elliptic integral and $g$ is a [doubly periodic](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Weierstrass%27s_elliptic_functions) meromorphic function : a **Weierstrass elliptic function**

Answer (score 3):

**Hint:** $f(x)=\int_{0}^x \dfrac{dt}{\sqrt{1+t^3}}$ then $f'(x)=\dfrac{1}{\sqrt{1+x^3}}$, and 
$$g'(y)=\dfrac{1}{f'(x)}=\sqrt{1+x^3}=\sqrt{1+g^3(y)}$$
with differentiation you find $k=\dfrac32$.

Answer (score 2):

$f'(x)=\frac{1}{\sqrt{1+x^3}}$

$g'(f(y))=\frac{1}{f'(y)}=\sqrt{1+y^3}$

$g'(y)=\sqrt{1+g^3(y)}$

$g''(y)=\frac{3g^2(y)g'(y)}{2\sqrt{1+g^3(y)}}=\frac{3}{2}g^2(y)$

$k=\frac{3}{2}$

Comment: $(t^{1/2})' =\frac12 t^{-1/2}$